# Adding two buttons on WFFM

Tags: wffm

We are trying to add more then one button in a WFFM form and each button will perform a different action.  Currently the only option is to have a `Submit` button.

We are using Sitecore 8.1 and WFFM in our solution.

Comment: Could you provide more detail about what the problem you're facing is? Have you consulted the WFFM documentation for adding custom actions?

Comment: He doesn't want to create a custom action, he's looking for a way to have two buttons.  By default WFFM only has the Submit button.  @Abhimanyu Singh could you describe what the second button will do?

Comment: My objective is to add button that will initially perform like "Back" ,"Redirect to page " or "Cancel" . </br> We will be reusing this feature to other website forms and it should be generic so that we can plug it any where .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I raised this issue with sitecore and they said the Current WFFM does not support this .

  Then i did some customization in existing WFFM  `\Views\Form\EditorTemplates\FormViewModel.cshtml` file .

- Created a button component that will read the data from paramater renderings
- I added two placeholder so that i can plug my button component

> @Html.Sitecore().Placeholder("wffm-before-submit")
>       
>       @Html.BootstrapSubmit()
>       
>       @Html.Sitecore().Placeholder("wffm-after-submit")

- Added buttton component is page with specific place holder

Answer (score 0):

There is no out of the box feature for adding two buttons in WFFM forms. However you can try adding a new button using jQuery (by basic DOM manipulation). Please refer this [link](https://doc.sitecore.net/web_forms_for_marketers/82/working_with_actions_and_validations/the_submit_button/walkthrough_configuring_the_submit_button) for more details on configuring submit button in WFFM forms

Comment: Can you include a little more details (ex. a code example) about how you would achieve this with JQuery.