# Button Text personalization in WFFM

Tags: wffm, personalization

Is it possible to personalize the Submit Button text in WFFM.

Our requirement is to display the different Button text based on the User type logged-in. We have a rule to identify the person type

Or do we need to duplicate the form just for changing the button text.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to personalize the Submit button text using the out-of-the-box module. Unlike the form fields which allows you to set `Rules` against the element, the Submit button only allows you to set a single value.

You need to create a duplicate of the form and use personalization to switch the form out.

One possible solution might be to create a rendering with some Javascript which sets the text of the button, and calling the script immediately should minimize any noticeable flicker of the text being changed on page load.

```html
@model RenderingModel

<script>
  var buttonText = @Html.Sitecore().Field("Button Text", new { DisableWebEdit = true });
  var $submitBtn = $(document.body.lastChild).prev('form').find(':submit');
  $submitBtn.prop('value', buttonText);
</script>
```

Create a new template with a field to hold `Button Text` and then create an item as the datasource of your rendering. You can then insert this rendering immediately following your WFFM Rendering.

The script uses the [jQuery prev()](https://api.jquery.com/prev/) selector to find the form, select [submit element](https://api.jquery.com/submit-selector/) and then set the text of the element. You can then use `Personalization Rules` to hide the rendering (when you want default text from the form to be shown) or switch the datasource to a different item for variations of the button text.

You can see an example in this [Codepen demo](https://codepen.io/jammykam/pen/ZrYdaP?editors=1000)

A slight variation of the above would be to [add a placeholder to the FormViewModel rendering](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/8606/135) and change the code to use the [closest() selector](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) rather than `prev()`. It accomplishes the same thing but you can then use placeholder restrictions to only allow this new rendering in that placeholder.